# Put a slot in every component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a component called **vue-select** that is a third-party packaged that I installed. I want to put a slot template in every instance of this component.
I mean I want to do something like this:

```
<v-select>
 <span slot="no-options">
   <li>sample text</li>
 </span>
</v-select>
```

and I don't want to do this in every **v-select** that I have in my project.
How can I do this to dry my code ?
thank You :)

Comment: If you want something to part of the component always, don't make it a slot. Simply put the piece of HTML into the template of the component.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović unfortunately this is a third-party package and its not my own component. So I can't access the html inside component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slot is useful when you **want** to make parts of component's template different. If you always want it to be the same piece of template, then don't make it a slot. Simply add the markup you want into the template of the component.

This is similar to not putting something as an argument of a function if you don't want to be possible to change it.

```
function spin (element) {
  const angle = 360
}
```

---

If you want an option to have some common content but still change it sometimes, put the default content in the `<slot>` tags in the template of the component.

This is similar to adding a default argument in a function:

```
function spin (element, angle = 360) { }
```

---

If you already have a third-party component which has defined slots and their default content, and thus you cannot change them, wrap them in a different component firstly and then use the wrapper component in the rest of the code.

This is similar to adding a new function which calls the previous one, but hard-codes some arguments.

```
function halfSpin (element) {
  spin(element, 180)
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is a third-party package and its not my own component. So I can't access the html inside component

Comment: Did you read my answer, @HamidOsouli? I explicitly mention that in the third part of my answer.